# What happens to previous Subscriptions in RxJS?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, reactive

While I'm pretty used to using RxJS, and reactive programming, there is one thing that's been bothering me, that I can't get my head around.

Let's say that we have a simple function that will be run every time some one clicks button SCAN

```
function scan() {
   this.startScaning(10).subscribe(scannedItem => console.log(scannedItem))
}
```

Inside our scan function, we use a startScanning method which starts scanning (i.e. for Bluetooth devices) for 10 seconds, and it returns an observable to which we subscribe and we log all the discovered devices/items.

OK, so far so good, but what bothers me is what happens if user clicks the button 10 times in a row. What happens to the previous subscriptions? And how am I supposed to handle this? Do I need to unsubscribe every time, do I need to unsubscribe at all?

A nice explanation would be appreciated, with possible further readings/examples, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would handle this would be to flip a boolean while the process is running and bind the button's `[disabled]` property to that value, e.g.

```
isScanning: boolean
function scan() {
    this.isScanning = true
    this.startScaning(10).subscribe({
        next: scannedItem => console.log(scannedItem),
        complete: () => this.isScanning = false
    })
}

<button (click)="scan()" [disabled]="isScanning">Click me!</button>
```

(you might also want to add some sort of indicator that it's processing while the button is disabled - I like to use Font Awesome's [spinner icons](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#animated) with `*ngIf="isScanning"` for that)

As for the rest, it depends on how exactly the `startScaning` method is implemented.  Most likely you'd have ten separate observables each of which would automatically complete ten seconds after its respective click, so there wouldn't be any need to worry about manually unsubscribing or anything unless it was a really heavy process (but IMO you should still disable the button anyway for UX reasons).

Looking at your question again, I assumed you're using Angular but you didn't actually say that.  If you're not, the general principle is the same, the only difference is you'll need to use a different way of setting the button's `disabled` state.

Comment: I'm using Rx in and outside of angular, so didn't want the question to be angular specific, but yeah your answer seems pretty good, I'll accept it later today, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could on the click change the function submit to another class that does nothing, and when the subscribe return the result call for a class to change the button again to call this function

It doesn't solve the RxJS problem just your problem, just make the button useless while waiting to the result

I suppose you also could use observables to  map each call to a variable, but in your case seems better to block the function call while the loop is running